# RegEx contain a combination of letters, numbers, and a special character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I'm finding a regular expression which adheres below rules.

Acceptance criteria: Password must contain a combination of letters, numbers, and at least a special character.`

Here is my Regex:

```
validates :password, presence: true,
format: { with: ^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*$)([^A-Za-z0-9])}
```

I am not all that great at regex, so any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need exactly one special character or at least one special character?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I need least one special character.

Comment: Please refer to [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following RegEx pattern

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*([a-z]|[A-Z]))([\x20-\x7E]){8,}$/
```

Let's look at what it is doing:

```
(?=.*\d) shows that the string should contain atleast one integer.
(?=.*([a-z]|[A-Z])) shows that the string should contain atleast one alphabet either from downcase or upcase.
([\x20-\x7E]) shows that string can have special characters of ascii values 20 to 7E.
{8,} shows that string should be minimum of 8 characters long. While you have not mentioned it should be at least 8 characters long but it is good to have.
```

If you're unsure about the ASCII values, you can google it or you could use the following instead:

```
  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*([a-z]|[A-Z]))(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]){8,}$/
```

As suggested in the comments, a better way can be:

```
/\A(?=.*\d)(?=.*([a-z]))(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]){8,}\z/i
```

Here:

```
\A represents beginning of string.
\z represents end of string.
/i represents case in-sensitive mode.
```

P.S: I have not tested it yet. May be I'll test and update later if required.

Comment: Nice answer! you can improve this regex by putting it in insensitive case and remove `|[A-Z]` use `i` attribute

Comment: You almost always want `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` in Ruby, `^` and `$` are beginning/ending of *line* whereas `\A` and `\z` are beginning/ending of *string*.

Comment: Do you mean this: `/\A(?=.*\d)(?=.*([a-z]|[A-Z]))(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]){8,}\z/i` ?